# Not able to insert data into hive elasticsearch index using spark SQL

Tags: scala, hadoop, elasticsearch, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have used the following steps in hive terminal to insert into elasticsearch index -

1. Create `hive` table pointing to elasticsearch index

   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_es(
   id string,
   name string
   )
   STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler'
   TBLPROPERTIES('es.resource = test/person', 'es.mapping = id');
2. Create a staging table and insert data into it

   Create table emp(id string,name string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',';

   load data local inpath '/home/monami/data.txt' into table emp;
3. Insert data from staging table into the hive elasticsearch index

   insert overwrite table test_es select * from emp;

I could browse through the hive elasticsearch index successfully following the above steps in `hive CLI`. But whenever I am trying to insert in the same way using SPARK SQL `hiveContext` object, I am getting the folllowing error -

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: class org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat$EsOutputCommitter not org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCommitter
```

Can you please let me know the reason for this error? If it is not possible to insert the same way using Spark, then what is the method to insert into hive elasticsearch index using Spark ?

Versions used - Spark 1.6, Scala 2.10, Elasticsearch 6.4, Hive 1.1

Comment: Same situation, waiting for anwser....